# Uniformly Continuous / Open Sets

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

*I am reading a paper about this system of differential equations:*

\begin{equation}
\left \{
\begin{split}
x'(t) = p(t)f(y(t))\\
y'(t) = q(t)g(x(t)).
\end{split}
\right.
\end{equation}

*I want to understand this section:*

The system has initial conditions
$x(a) = x_0$, $y(a) = c$, denoted by $x(t):= x(t,c)$, $y(t):= y(t,c)$ for $t \geq a$.

Let $U$ be defined by
    $$U = \left \{c \in \mathbb{R} : \text{there exists} \ t \geq a \ \text{such that} \ y(t,c) > 0  \right\},$$

*(Clearly U is nonempty since I can choose $c>0$.)*

Next, we want to show that $U$ is an open set. Indeed, if $c \in U$, then there exists $t_0 > a$ such that $y(t_0, c)> 0$. Note that
$$y(t_0) = y(a) + \int_a^{t_0} q(s)g(x(s))ds,$$
we have
$$y(t_0, c^*) - y(t_0, c) = \int_a^{t_0} q(s)[g(x(s, c^*))- g(x(s, c))]ds.$$

Since solutions of differential equations are continuously dependent on initial values, for all $c^*$ sufficiently close to $c$, $g(x(s, c^*) - g(x(s, c)) \to  0$ uniformly for $s \in [a, t_0]$ as $c^* \to c$. Thus, $y(t_0, c^*) > 0$ for all $c^*$ close to $c$ and $c^* \in U$. Therefore, $U$ is open.

*I want to make sure I understand why $U$ is open. Is this because since the set contains all c including the initial condition which results in $y(t,c)>0$, so we have $y^{-1}((0,\infty))$; but $(0, \infty)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, so since $y$ is a continuous mapping, $y^{-1}((0, \infty))$ is open in $U$?*

Comment: Clearly $U \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then $U$ is open if for every $x \in U$, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ is contained in U.

Comment: Yes, I know that definition of open, but how does that connect to uniformly continuous? Because I can always create a neighborhood around c for c* sufficiently close to c?